# Java Cant add subclassed object to list

Tags: java

Parent class:

```
public class Action
    {
        private String eventId;
        private List<ActionArgument> arguments;
        //action to perform when this action is done
        private List<? extends Action> onCompleteActions;

        public Action(){}

        public Action(String eventId, List<ActionArgument> arguments, List<? extends Action> onCompleteActions)
        {
            this.eventId = eventId;
            this.arguments = arguments;
            this.onCompleteActions = onCompleteActions;
        }

        public String getEventId()
        {
            return eventId;
        }
        public void setEventId(String eventId)
        {
            this.eventId = eventId;
        }
        public List<ActionArgument> getArguments()
        {
            return arguments;
        }
        public void setArguments(List<ActionArgument> arguments)
        {
            this.arguments = arguments;
        }
        public List<? extends Action> getOnCompleteActions()
        {
            return onCompleteActions;
        }
        public void setOnCompleteActions(List<? extends Action> onCompleteActions)
        {
            this.onCompleteActions = onCompleteActions;
        }
    }
```

extended class:

```
public class UserDefinedAction extends Action
{
    // body not important
}
```

Some service:

```
private boolean arrangeBefore(List<? extends Action> defaultActions, UserDefinedAction action)
    {
        String actionToFind = action.getDoBefore();
        boolean actionFound = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < defaultActions.size(); i++)
        {
            if(defaultActions.get(i).getEventId().toUpperCase().equals(actionToFind.toUpperCase()))
            {
                defaultActions.add(i, action);
                return true;
            }
...
```

So I have an error here: `defaultActions.add(i, action);` which says "

```
add
(int,
capture<? extends com.myPackage.Action>)
in List cannot be applied
to
(int,
com.myPackage.UserDefinedAction)
```

"

Can someone explain to me why this doesnt work?

Comment: If I do that I get this error:add
(int,
capture<? extends com.myPackage.Action>)
in List cannot be applied
to
(int,
com.myPackage.Action)

Comment: You can't add anything inside a list with upper bounds - `List<? extends Action>`. You can only add `null`, or the elements you previously fetched from it.

Comment: @RohitJain: "or the elements you previously fetched from it." How does the compiler keep track of that?

Answer (score 1):

A simple possibility to consider is:

- Make a defensive copy of the input list in the constructor.
- Store it simply as a List<Action>.

In general, it's useful to remember the **PECS** acronym - *Producer Extends, Consumer Super*. If you want to add elements to a List with a bounded type variable or wildcard, you'd want to express it with `super` rather than `extends`. For example, List<? super A> means that the list member type is some *superclass* of an A.

Comment: +1. `List<Action>` should work well here. Note that a `List<Action>` can store subclasses of Action already, no need for a wildcard just for that.

Comment: Right. In this particular case, it doesn't seem called for. You *could* accept an arbitrary List<? super Action> in the constructor, or have a getter that accepts as an argument the List<? super Action> to be filled -- but I don't see how either would be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an argument of any type to a method with a wildcard in it.  Here, you have a `List<? extends Action>`, and you're attempting to add a `UserDefinedAction`.

But Java doesn't know the exact generic type of your `List`; it assumes it could be anything, even something like `List<SomeOtherAction>`.  It can't allow you to add a `UserDefinedAction` to your list for that reason.  For this reason, Java disallows you to call such a method.

To get around this, you will need to define a generic type parameter on your `Action` class:

```
public class Action<A extends Action>
```

Then you can replace all `<? extends Action>` in that class with `<E>`.  This way, an `Action<Action>` will be able to handle a `List<Action>`.

Next, define `A` in `UserDefinedAction` to be `UserDefinedAction`.  This way, a `UserDefinedAction` can handle a `List<UserDefinedAction>`, which will allow you to `add` a `UserDefinedAction`.

```
public class UserDefinedAction extends Action<UserDefinedAction>
```

Alternatively, you could, for more flexibility, define `UserDefinedAction` this way:

```
public class UserDefinedAction<A extends UserDefinedAction> extends Action<A>
```

... and use a `UserDefinedAction<UserDefinedAction>` instance.  This would allow further subclasses of `UserDefinedAction` to define the generic type parameter `A` the way they want.

Comment: So what would you recommend for what im trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, that wasnt there when I posted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signature of the method and use generics in it:

```
public <A extends Action> void arrangeBefore(List<A> actionList, A action) {
    actionList.add(action);
}
```

Note that this change assumes that the methods used from `A action` in `arrangeBefore` belongs to `Action` class only.